# How to pass multiple arguments in an inline event listener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looping through a list of songs coming from a database with a button that deletes the song targetted

```
<div v-for="(song, index) of songs" :key="index">
  ...
  ...
  <button @click="deleteSong(song._id)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

then in the method

```
deleteSong(id) {
  axios.delete("/api/songs/" + id)
}
```

What I also want is to get the target event object in order to instantly delete the row without having to refresh the page

I tried `@click="deleteSong(e, song._id)"` and some other things but I always get`undefined`, any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get to the underlying event you can use `$event`

see https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#methods-in-inline-handlers

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#methods-in-inline-handlers) show, `$event` can be used to refer to the associated event:

```
<button @click="deleteSong(song._id, $event)">Delete</button>
```